# How to make columns in Javadoc comments?

Tags: java, formatting, javadoc

So I'm learning Java right now, and I'm wondering how to make my Javadoc comments look more organized.
Specifically, I want my parameters to be laid out something like this:

```
@param parameterName    parameterType    Description of the parameter
```

With three separate columns with whitespace in between.
How would you do this?

Comment: This is javadoc official guide: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html

Comment: If you're in IntelliJ, try this trick. Above the function statement, write a ```/**```, and hit enter, it'll generate argument names and the return variable for you with javadoc formatting and everything.

Comment: Works in eclipse too. @Siddhartha

Comment: @Siddhartha Also Netbeans. Not that it appears to be in any way relevant.

Comment: Ah I was unaware. That's good to hear.

Comment: just out of curiosity: what benefit do you expect having the parameter type in the parameter description (in contrast to `@link` or `@see` for e.g. non standard types)